# UITableView with Sections Repeating cell data in all the sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I Know same question has been asked before , but it did not help.

I am trying to add section titles to my UITableView. I am able to create the sections and count the number of elements in each section properly, , the cells are repeated the data in all the sections.

I am posting only relevant code -

My model is -

```
 import UIKit
 struct Product:Equatable {
  let imagename: UIImage }

  var productarray = [Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CakeImage")),
                Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PeasImge")),Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "vectorlogo")),
                Product(imagename: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue"))]
```

The ProductViewController is -

```
 import UIKit

 class ProductViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
 let sections = ["Section A", "Section B","Section C", "Section D"]
 let rowspersection = [1, 1,1,1]
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self   
 }
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return sections.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return rowspersection[section]
    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let data = productarray[indexPath.row]
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
     cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
     cell.myParent = self
       return cell
  }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch(section) {
    case 0:return "Section A"
     case 1:return "Section B"
    case  2:return "Section C"
    case  3 :return "Section D"
    default :return ""
        
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the above only the first image of the productarray i.e. "[Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CakeImage"))," is repeated in all the sections as shown in the image below:-

[image]

I want all the images/cell to be in the respective sections and not just one image/cell to be repeated in all the sections.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in every section indexPath start with zero so it display first index of *productarray*.

```
let data = productarray[indexPath.row]
```

replace with

```
let data = productarray[indexPath.row + indexPath.section]
```

**Edit**

```
var index = indexPath.row
if indexPath.section != 0, rowspersection.count > indexPath.section - 1{
   index += rowspersection[indexPath.section - 1] 
}
if index < productarray.count{
  let data = productarray[index]
  cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
}
```

**Edit Checkout**
Replace this methods

```
func updateCart(cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    var index = indexPath.row
    if indexPath.section != 0, rowspersection.count > indexPath.section - 1{
        index += rowspersection[indexPath.section - 1]
    }
    
    if index < productarray.count{
        let product = productarray[index]
        
        //Update Cart with product
        cart.updateCart(with: product)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Checkout (\(cart.items.count))"
    }
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell   {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as!   ProductTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self // original issue was here, now resolved.
    
    var index = indexPath.row
    if indexPath.section != 0, rowspersection.count > indexPath.section - 1{
        index += rowspersection[indexPath.section - 1]
    }
    
    if index < productarray.count{
        let data = productarray[index]
        cell.name?.text = data.name
        cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
        
        let product = productarray[index]
        cell.setButton(state: self.cart.contains(product: product))
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: -when i follow your code, and I do 2 images each in just 2 sections i.e 
let sections = ["Section A", "Section B"] & let rowspersection = [2,2] , the second image/cell of the first section(Section A) gets repeated in
the first image/cell of the second section(Section B), the original first image/cell of the section(Section B) is nowhere to be found. So,
expected images - Section A- CakeImage,PeasImge & Section B - vectorlogo, blue
unanticipated images - Section A- CakeImage,PeasImge & Section B - PeasImge, blue

How to sort it ?  Note - I don’t want to change the model.

Comment: yes, your edited answer is working fine. Upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: okay, there is a stumbling block - when I click on add button for a row of the first section, say "section a" it adds and Checkout(0) becomes 1 i.e. Checkout(1). Till here, its okay, but when I click on add button for a row of another  section, say "section b", Checkout(1) again becomes 0 i.e. it becomes Checkout(0). How to straighten it out ??

Comment: @askit Please share code and your requirement properly so i can understand

Comment: The complete code is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012036/7444874

Comment: Again a glitch. Supposse there are 4 sections(see image above). Till add button of sections A and B it works fine, but the moment add button of section C is clicked,Checkout again again decreases !

Comment: moreover ,  the cells are not properly(initial problem), when there are 4 rows with 2 cells each, the first row cells are fine, but the consequent rows all go haywire ! So, both the issues are not resolved. Please  look into it.

Comment: perhaps PGDev's suggestion is right, i.e. changing the model, but the I'll have to change the productviewcontrooller. That will also do. The crux is that I  want it to be divided into sections and add to cart to function properly.

Comment: @askit problem is that section A with 4 row and section B with 4 row and this row use same object from productArray when you select same object from any cell it decrease because check this method *func contains(product: Product) -> Bool {
        let item = items.filter { $0.product == product }
        return item.first != nil
    }*

Comment: sill glitchy - Model data in short - a:blue,b:CakeImage,c:vectorlogo, d:PeasImge,e:castle,f:scoobydoo,g:ufo,h:wolfsky,i:universe,j:werewolf,k:galaxy.  ProductViewController relevant
data - let sections = ["Section A", "Section B","Section C", "Section D","Section E"]
    let rowspersection = [2,3,2,2,2], and switch accordingly. but the images in Simulator are in order section A:blue,CakeImage.  B: vectorlogo, PeasImge, castle. C:PeasImge, castle. D:PeasImge, castle. E:PeasImge, castle.
Clicking on Add also acts insanely.

Comment: With all due respect, I am removing it as the selected answer, but not removing the upvote. I hope you do not offended.

Comment: @askit OK np, but why? please tell me the reason.

Comment: because my problem is not sorted out, maybe you have not read yesterday's comment. Its not working fully. I know you have tried a lot, but still not sorted.

Comment: i solved your problem that discribe in your question. and try to solve other issue that not discribe in your question. you need to create other question for other issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

Since you've a single `row` in each `section`, everytime you use `indexPath.row` which is `0` for the 1st row, you end up accessing `productarray[0]` for each `row` in every `section`.

That's the reason all the rows are same because all of them are filled with `productarray[0]`.

**Solution:**

Simply use `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath.row`

```
let data = productarray[indexPath.section]
```

---

**Note:** Instead of making 3 different `arrays`, you can create a single `array` of custom type and use that as the `dataSource` of your `tableView`. **Example:**

```
struct Section {
    let name: String
    let products: [Product]
}

let sections = [
    Section(name: "Section A", products: [Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CakeImage"))]),
    Section(name: "Section B", products: [Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PeasImge"))]),
    Section(name: "Section C", products: [Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "vectorlogo"))]),
    Section(name: "Section D", products: [Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue"))]),
]
```

Use `sections` `array` as the dataSource. This will avoid a lot of confusion.

Comment: okay, yes, its workin when I change it to indexpath.section, but I have presented the simplest code to you. How would that go, if  say in the above ProductViewController, modify - let sections = ["Section A", "Section B"]
& let rowspersection = [2,2] i.e. 2 images  each in just 2 ssections Note that I do not want to change the model because the real code is more. Kindly look into my problem. I will be indebted.

Comment: Well, that was just a suggestion based on your current code. Anyways glad that the issue is resolved. Happy coding 

Comment: Do accept if the answer worked so others won't invest time resolving it.

Comment: @Yes, the the question is answered, but the original issue, I am afraid, is not fully resolved. I had presented the simplest code to you. Please read my comment above.

Comment: I did that. And you need to ask a separate question for other problems. A question is considered answered when the problem statement present in the original question is resolved.